# std::vector for_each error C3867 function call missing argument list

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, stdvector

I want to use the `for_each` syntax with `std::vector<std::string>` but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'IO::checkFilePath': 

function call missing argument list; use '&IO::checkFilePath' to create a pointer to member
```

Here is my code:

```
void checkFilePath(const std::string& filepath);
void checkFileList(const std::vector<std::string>& filelist);

void IO::checkFilePath(const std::string& filepath)
{
    if (!boost::filesystem::exists(filepath) || !boost::filesystem::is_directory(filepath))
    {
        //do smth
    }

}

void IO::checkFileList(const std::vector<std::string>& filelist)
{
        std::for_each(filelist.begin(), filelist.end(), checkFilePath);
}
```

Comment: it appears that `checkFilePath` is a member function and you can't use it directly with for_each, make that function a global function and everything should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you intend for `checkFilePath` to be a member, replace the use of it in the `for_each` algorithm with:

```
 [&](std::string const& s){return checkFilePath(s);}
```

and it will capture `this` and call the method.  The above requires C++11, which you may not have.  If you have C++03, you either have to use `std::bind` or `boost::bind` or write your own functor to capture `this` or the state required to solve the `checkFilePath` problem.

If your `checkFilePath` does not depend on the state of `this`, simply make the method `static` and your existing code should compile.  (Alternatively, make it a free function).

Answer (score 1):

Function checkFilePath is a non-static member function. It can be called using an object of type IO. So you may not simply specify it as the third parameter of the for_each algorithm. 
It would be simpler if this function would be a static member function.